# Apple OS X Yosemite Email Viewing Preferences

Tags: macos, email, preferences

Previous versions of OS X had a dropdown menu under Viewing in Mail Preferences that allowed you to choose the type of heading or no heading at all when viewing an email.  The drop down menu is still there but now there is only one choice available: "headers".  I can find no mention of this issue on any Apple forums.  Maybe no one else uses it?  Or am I the only one with this issue?  Would appreciate any suggestions for a fix.  I often save emails as PDFs and prefer not to have header info showing.

Comment: so the use classic layout is no longer there?

Comment: no, use classic layout is still there and I am using it, but the Viewing Preferences are the same either way.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have Yosemite to confirm but found this:

[10.10.2 Update](http://www.applevis.com/blog/apple-mac-os-x-news/features-and-bugs-os-x-yosemite)

> The button to show or hide headers when composing mail messages has moved to the toolbar of the composition window.

Comment: This button just alternates between default headers (sender, recipient, reply-to, subject on the left and the date on the right) and detailed headers even tho the roll-over text for the button says "show (or hide) all headers"